# How to stop new pages from always aligning to the right of the spine

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I'm having this very troublesome problem where adding new pages by either placing a document or adding manually, creates a right-formatted page from my master spread that defaults to the right of the spine, even if there is space on the left. 
If I add two new pages, instead of making a left-right spread, I get two right pages to the right of spine.

**In the image:** spread 23-4 I had to drag one page left across the spine, the following spreads show how they are added. 
[image]

I'll be much obliged to learn how to set things right, that is, new pages default to a left-right spread with spine between.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely based on the `Allow Document Pages to Shuffle` and `Allow Selected Spread to Shuffle` options for pages.

[image]

Now, I *wish* I could tell you exactly how to set these to overcome your issue. But I can't. I much prefer InDesign CS6 as opposed to *any* CC version. With InDesign CS6, these options toggle settings, but you *can't* tell what will change. The checkmarks seemingly have *no relation* to what *actually* can happen in the Pages Panel. That *may have* been improved in CC versions.

So... if things aren't working as you expect, try toggling the settings. Mostly the Allow Pages to Shuffle will alter how pages may be added.